# Prime number: How does this code works?

Tags: java

This code calculates prime numbers, but how does it work?
I need a clear explanation of what the if(band) at the end is doing.

```
public class Primes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m;
        boolean band;

        for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
            m = 2;
            band = true;

            while (band && m <i) {    
                if (i % m == 0) {
                    band = false;
                } else {
                    m++;
                }
            }

            if (band) {
                System.out.println("The number " + i + " is prime");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not `clear` in above program ??

Comment: I dont understand the logic

Comment: This simply prints prime numbers between 2 - 99. What is unclear ? How this question get +2?

Comment: If you are working with any good editor like Eclipse did you tried debugging?

Comment: It simply iterates the numbers 2-99 and for each number it checks if there's is no smaller positive integer > 1 that divides it without a reminder (if true --> the number is prime).

Comment: Now would be a good time to start using an IDE. Being able to debug is a core part of programming.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply printing prime numbers between 2 -99.

From the for loop it iterates numbers between 2 - 99. Inside for loop it checks whether particular number(i) is divisible by m without any remaining. If there are remaining increase the value of m by one until m < i and iterate the process. If there is no remaining then it is a prime number, then make band to true and print the output. Since band is true now it will exit the while loop and go to next iteration of for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming the variable `band` to `i_is_prime` and then try to trace the logic.  The key line is this one:

```
if (i%m==0) {
```

That line returns `true` if `m` divides evenly into `i`, which means `i` isn't prime.

Answer (score 1):

This method is to find all prime Numbers less than 100

```
// This is the dividend
int m;    
// Whether can't divisible
boolean band;    

//  From 100 all digital lookup
for (int i=2;i<100;i++){ 
        // Divisor increasing from 2
    m=2;
    // If not divisible, here defined as cannot be divided exactly by first, if we can find a divisor aliquot, the current number is not a prime 
    band=true;
    // From 2 to the current number one by one
    while(band && m <i){    
            // Remainder of 0, explain aliquot, band = false, jump out the while
        if(i%m==0){
            band=false;
        }else{
        // Remainder is not 0, i cannot be divided exactly by m, continue to verify the m + 1
            m++;
        }
    }
    // From 2 to i-1 cannot be divisible, that i was a prime number
    if(band){
        System.out.println("The number "+i+" is prime");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- After coming out of while "if(band)" is checking that IS COUNTER 'i' IS
  PRIME or NOT.
- You should use meaningful names for identifiers, so change BAND to
  IS_PRIME.
- And algorithm you used is very time consuming try to implement
  Sieve of Eratosthenes it have O(nlog(log(n))) computational
  complexity which is great and simple.

[Check  Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Number_theoretic/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)